# Why are these ferns growing poorly?

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, ferns

I bought these three ferns at the same time. They came in 10cm pots so I planted them in 20-30cm pots. They are in a shady location with a limited amount of sunlight for some of the day.

I water them once a week just a little bit as the soil seems to stay damp for a while. I make sure the soil isn't waterlogged.

They grew a little when first planted, but since then they haven't grown at all, and the new growth seems to die or be generally unhealthy.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

They may be too dry, and the soil may be too fluffy & dry. Maybe try misting them also. Ferns often do better with more moisture & humidity than these seem to show. Also, maybe try carefully remove expired material. They may need different soil. They may have been given too much nutrient before they were purchased; new soil might help alleviate that also. And some gravel etc in the bottoms of the containers to assist with drainage. Good question & good illustrations!